# Extension Migration : Aoe_Scheduler

Tags: magento2, extensions, migration, crontab, schedule

I'm working on Shop Migration from 1.x to 2.x

For Aoe_Scheduler module it seems that there is no M2 version. so what is the best way to get all module's features in my Magento 2 shop:

- Migrate the extension
- Get other M2 Extension with same feature. Examples ?
- No need to have this module in M2, just use crontab

Could anyone answer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just migrate my M1 to M2 and was able to find a similar module to AOE_Scheduler.  Use this composer to install:

Name of the composer package: wyomind/cronscheduler

```
composer require wyomind/cronscheduler
php bin/magento module:enable -c Wyomind_CronScheduler
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on this for a while:
https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager

Hopefully it helps you out!